# inside while loop used fflush does not work

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    char arr[20];
    int a;
    int count=0;
    while(1){
        printf("enter string with space:");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%[^\n]%*c", arr);
        printf("enter integer:");
        scanf("%d",&a);
        count++;
        if(count==4){
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to read string with space and I have to use this code. I wrote this in while loop and I want to read string and after integer number and it does not work.

Output:

```
enter string with space:hey hey

enter integer:159

enter string with space:enter integer:
```

But output should be:

```
enter string with space:hey hey

enter integer:159

enter string with space:.... heyy

enter integer: 1235
```

Comment: Why do you "_have to_ us this code_"?  If that is the code you must use, how can we help?  The code you need will necessarily be different.

Comment: Please take a look at [Using fflush(stdin)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2979209)

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 I could not see the solution to this here. and I was just told to use this code while read string with space

Comment: I edit my question can you look again please @Clifford

Comment: I typed incorrectly while editing the question, now I've edited it.

Comment: You still state that you _must_ use this code; implying that it cannot be changed.

Comment: Also you read the integer _after_ the string; not "_string and after integer_".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> enter string with space:enter integer:
> ```

This happens because after you enter integer input, `\n` is still left in the stream. `%[` does not skip leading whitespace unlike most other format specifiers. Change `scanf("%[^\n]%*c", arr);` to `scanf(" %[^\n]%*c", arr);` so it manually skips the leading whitespace before taking input.

As for `fflush(stdin)`, that is undefined behavior (see [Using `fflush(stdin)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2979209)). @Clifford already provides two nice solutions to that issue.

Comment: indeed; my answer is to the original question, not the edited question - which is a different question that it originally appeared.

Answer (score 2):

`fflush()` is not defined input streams such as `stdin`. You will find that it works on Microsoft's C library, but not GNU.

Your `scanf()` call is incorrect. The first format specifier is incorrect, and you have no format specifier for `string` ;

```
scanf("%*[^\n]%*c") ;
```

will discard any remaining buffered characters to the end of the line inclusive.  It accepts no input - it is not clear what `string` is or what you want to do with it.  I'd suggest using a separate input call for that, for clarity.

Another somewhat less arcane solution is:

```
int c ;
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) { }
```

Comment: I was just told to use fflush code while read string with space and I typed incorrectly something while editing the question, now I've edited it.

Comment: @jack1919 : But it is still incorrect in exactly the same way, changing `string` to `arr` does not change that.  You have omitted the `*` in `%*[^\n]`.  Never transcribe your code manually, copy & paste it for accuracy.  Otherwise you are asking about code we cannot see while posting misleading code.

Comment: Note this is an answer to the original question before it was edited, and also to the question implied in the title.  It does not address the whole question as it now stands.